# Does Google Shopping offer search in local stores?

Tags: google-shopping

I would like to find out which local stores have  a product I need. Does Google Shopping offer such search? I don't find it.

If not, what are some ways?

Comment: There should be an "available nearby" checkbox, although, from experience, I can tell you that it rarely works. So, yes, Google offers it, but no, they don't do a good job of finding local products.